# How to make Firefox windows style less space consuming?

Tags: firefox, window, style, personalization

Firefox takes up so much space on small screens, so I'm searching for solutions that make firefox' interface less space consuming on ubuntu 12.04 with gnome3.
Good examples are the chromium-style, but chromium is kind of slow in gnome3.

Chromium does it, firefox on osx does it. Is this also possible on ubuntu via a custom modification or something?
Here a screenshot of what I am thinking about:

Firefox on OSX: https://wiki.mozilla.org/images/5/50/Firefox-4-Mockup-i06-%28OSX%29-%28TabsTop%29-%28Persona%29.png

Thanks for your help.

Comment: It look this way in ubuntu anyway. Menu bar is not shown. If it's shown, you can look for a setting in *View* menu. Themes are usable and other toolbars are posibble to be toggled. I didn't get the point of your question.

Comment: The problem is that firefox takes up so much space on small screens. I'm using gnome3 so the menu bar is shown. In chromium I was able to choose whether I want to have the ubuntu window style or a less space consuming style. The close/minimize/maximize buttons went to the left side of the tabs, window frame was removed and so was the menu bar. Since I'm on gnome3, removing the menu bar would not make much sense, except there is another smart solution. But I think there could be other solutions, for example just removing the window frame. I don't need it. Sorry, this question was not percise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only difference I can see is the Menu Bar. You can disable it and any other toolbars appearing on Firefox (I don't know wich ones you have enabled) in `View > Toolbars` menu and it can look exactly as it looks in OSX.

Comment: Removing the menu bar helped a bit. Also I was able to make the icons in Firefox smaller (right click > Customize). But on my screen in Firefox the title frame is really annoying. Is it possible to disable it for firefox only?

Comment: I don't think so. Maybe with a different theme. I use Xfce (xubuntu) and not Unity or Gnome3. Xfce has some themes with very reduced frame boxes (including title). Not sure something like that exists for Unity or Gnome 3.

Comment: You may use full screen mode (hit F11 on your keyboard).